# Syntax error on mysql , cannot detect where it is:

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

As mall background:

This is a query where I am looking for keywords inside a string.

I explode the string with the " " space:

```
$words = explode(" ", $searchstring);
```

Then I separate them by commas:

```
$commaSeparatedString = implode(", ", $words);
```

Then I perform the query:

```
$searchQuery = sprintf("SELECT * FROM solution T1 join solution_tags_intermediate T2
                        on T1.ID_SOLUTION = T2.ID_SOLUTION
                        join solution_tags T3 on T2.ID_SOLUTION_TAGS = T3.ID_SOLUTION_TAGS
                        WHERE T3.SOLUTION_TAGS_NAME IN '%s'", $commaSeparatedString);
```

I execute the query:

```
$resultSet = $DBConnect->query($searchQuery);
```

I get the following errors:

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\wamp\www\helpdesk\index.php on line 21

Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::fetch_assoc() in C:\wamp\www\helpdesk\index.php on line 27
```

Line 21 is:

```
if($resultSet->num_rows = 0){ /*more code here*/}
```

And line27 is:

```
while($tableData = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()){/*print some stuff here*/}
```

As far as I am aware that is the correct syntax of the query, but phpmyadmin says it ain't. Here is the query I am actually executing:

```
SELECT * FROM solution T1 join solution_tags_intermediate T2 
on T1.ID_SOLUTION = T2.ID_SOLUTION 
join solution_tags T3 
on T2.ID_SOLUTION_TAGS = T3.ID_SOLUTION_TAGS 
WHERE T3.SOLUTION_TAGS_NAME IN 'internet, renweb'
```

The error phpmyadmin throws is:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
 for the right syntax to use near ''internet, renweb' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been working on this project for over 8 hours now, I know it's something simple probably but I just can't get to figure out what is the problem.

Comment: `where field in ()` - brackets

Comment: More specifically `WHERE T3.SOLUTION_TAGS_NAME IN ('%s')", $commaSeparatedString);` AND `$resultSet->num_rows = 0` - did you mean `$resultSet->num_rows == 0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query:

```
  SELECT * FROM solution T1 join solution_tags_intermediate T2 
    on T1.ID_SOLUTION = T2.ID_SOLUTION 
    join solution_tags T3 
    on T2.ID_SOLUTION_TAGS = T3.ID_SOLUTION_TAGS 
    WHERE T3.SOLUTION_TAGS_NAME IN ('internet', 'renweb')
```

You also have a problem here:

```
if($resultSet->num_rows = 0){ /*more code here*/}
```

You need to use the comparison symbol `==` like this:

```
if($resultSet->num_rows == 0){ /*more code here*/}
```

Comment: It brings the results back, now the problem is how can I enclose each word in my variable $commaSeparatedString inside  "", like 'internet', 'renweb'? since the output of what I'm doing on my code is:

('internet, renweb')

Comment: $commaSeparatedString2 = "'" . join(', ',$commaSeparatedString ) . "'";

Answer (score 3):

This is one problem in addition to the query syntax.

```
if($resultSet->num_rows = 0){ /*more code here*/}
```

You are setting `$resultSet` to equal `0`! You need to do a comparison here, not an assignment.

Comment: How can I compare if the number of rows from $resultSet is equal to 0 then?

Comment: @Yisera Use a comparison operator `===` or `==`

Comment: Still getting the error saying: 

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\helpdesk\index.php on line 19

where line 19 is

 if($resultSet->num_rows == 0){/*some code*/}

Any idea?

Comment: @Yisera You probably don't have a valid result set.  Do you handle errors in your code at all or verify you have a valid result set before trying to operate against it?

Comment: I'm not really good at backend development, I just operate things and figure out what the error is on the go

Comment: @Yisera That doesn't mean you shouldn't try to write good functional code does it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43781/discussion-between-yisera-and-mike-brant)

Answer (score 0):

```
$words = explode(" ", mysql_real_escape_string($searchstring)); 

$commaSeparatedString = "'".implode("','", $words)."'"; 


$searchQuery = sprintf("SELECT * FROM solution T1 join solution_tags_intermediate T2
                        on T1.ID_SOLUTION = T2.ID_SOLUTION
                        join solution_tags T3 on T2.ID_SOLUTION_TAGS = T3.ID_SOLUTION_TAGS
                        WHERE T3.SOLUTION_TAGS_NAME IN (%s)", $commaSeparatedString);
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Whilst @raygo has got the syntax right, I wonder if you should even be using `IN`? `IN` will look for `T3.SOLUTION_TAGS_NAME` values of exactly `internet` or `renweb`.

IF you are actually wanting to search for results where `T3.SOLUTION_TAGS_NAME` CONTAINS all of those terms and in any order then you want to do a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM solution T1 join solution_tags_intermediate T2 
on T1.ID_SOLUTION = T2.ID_SOLUTION 
join solution_tags T3 
on T2.ID_SOLUTION_TAGS = T3.ID_SOLUTION_TAGS 
WHERE T3.SOLUTION_TAGS_NAME LIKE '%internet%'
AND T3.SOLUTION_TAGS_NAME LIKE '%renweb%'
```

Remember that that will not be a hugely efficient query and cannot use indexes well, but should be fine for a small dataset. If you have lots of data then you should be using a dedicated search system. At my company we use Apache Solr, but I'd only suggest crossing that bridge if you need to.

If you need some PHP to help you make the query use something along the lines of:

```
<?php
$searchstring = trim($searchstring);
$terms = explode(' ', $searchstring);

// Make WHERE clause
$where_clause = 'WHERE ';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $where_clause .= "T3.SOLUTION_TAGS_NAME LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%' AND ";
}
$where_clause = substr($where_clause, 0, -5);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM solution T1 join solution_tags_intermediate T2 
on T1.ID_SOLUTION = T2.ID_SOLUTION 
join solution_tags T3 
on T2.ID_SOLUTION_TAGS = T3.ID_SOLUTION_TAGS ' . $where_clause;
```